# "quit" read as nil field?

Tags: lua, love2d

I am making a menu file for my game, and it's can't call "quit" as a field. It always returns nil. Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Note, it is declared earlier in the code and the other button function does work. Thanks!

```
function love.mousepressed( x, y, button )
  if button == "l" then
    for k, v in pairs(buttons) do
      local ins = insideBox( x, y, v.x - (v.w/2), v.y - (v.h/2), v.w, v.h)

      if ins then
        if v.action == "play" then
          loadState("game")
        end
      end
      if ins then
        if v.action == "quit" then
          love.event.quit()
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What isn't working exactly? You can't trigger the `love.event.quit()` call? Or the `love.event.quit()` call isn't doing anything?

Comment: love.event.quit() is triggering, but the field "quit" is returning as nil. I thought it could be the v.action == "quit" part, but that's called earlier in the code

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the return value of `love.event.quit()` so I don't know how you know what it is returning. Do you mean that it just isn't quitting your game? Is `love.event.quit()` a function you wrote? If so include it in your post.

Comment: love.event.quit() is built in the love2d engine, and I believe it takes no args and returns nothing, and it should work like it is. I've made it work with a love.keypressed function, but mousepressed never works for me.

Comment: Are you sure that `if` block is being executed? Can you print the value of `button`, `ins`, and `v.action` when it fails?

Comment: I am quite certain, as the Start function works. It's just reading the "quit" as nil, that's what im wondering

Comment: What does `reading the "quit" as nil` mean? You aren't *using* the return value of `love.event.quit()` anywhere so you *can't* be seeing it to know that it was `nil`. Do you mean you are getting an error for `attempt to call nil`? What **exactly** are you seeing that makes you say `"quit" as nil`?

Comment: The exact message is "Attempted to index field "quit" (a nil value)". I've used love.event.quit() before, and it should work without returning it or needing to give it args. For some reason it's indexing a field.

Comment: You can use that function in other code you said? What version of love? Do you have to load `love.event` manually in your code for that to work? Are you accidentally overwriting `love` or `love.event` in your code somewhere?

Comment: I have made it work in another game by using a love.keypressed function, and the same love.event.quit(), and it also has worked with a love.event.push('quit') in a love.keypressed function. It only fails when I started using the mouse.

Comment: Wait, "Atempted to index field "quit" (a nil value)"? Are you sure you used `love.event.quit()` Are you sure this is the code that is throwing that error? Because "attempt to index" means you tried to do `love.event.quit.something` or `love.event.quit['something']` or similar and not that you used `love.event.quit()` since that would say something like `attempt to call field 'quit' (a nil value)`.

Comment: I'm certainly using love.event.quit(), I can try something else if this doesn't work, thanks for the help for now

Comment: Check for "fancy" characters in that code. Then make *absolutely* sure that it is *this* line that is triggering that error because, at least with stock lua, that error shouldn't be able to come from that usage.

Comment: @TaylorBrown He didn't say you're not using `love.event.quit()`, he said that line is probably not the culprit. There is nothing in the code shown that is indexing a variable named `quit`, so the problem is likely somewhere else.If you're getting an error, *include that in your post*, including the entire stack trace, and make sure the relevant code is in the post. Saying it's "returning nil" is objectively wrong, that's *not* the problem you're encountering, making it very hard for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you have `play` and `quit` bound to the same button? o.O

Also, there's no need to check `ins` twice. Duplicate code should be a red flag:

```
  if ins then
    if v.action == "play" then
      loadState("game")
    end
  end
  if ins then
    if v.action == "quit" then
      love.event.quit()
    end
  end
```

That could be:

```
  if ins then
    if v.action == "play" then
      loadState("game")
    elseif v.action == "quit" then
      love.event.quit()
    end
  end
```

But short of using a debugger, here's how you track down such problems:

**1.** Create a file called [`conf.lua`](https://love2d.org/wiki/Config_Files) in your project folder.

**2.** Have at least this much inside it, to attach a console to your app:

```
function love.conf(t)
    t.console = true  -- Attach a console (Windows only)
end
```

**3.** Add debugging output to your `mousepressed` function so you can see what's going on.

First define this somewhere early in your app execution. Handy printing function:

```
 function printf(...) print(string.format(...)) end
```

Then add some debugging stuff to your function:

```
 function love.mousepressed(x, y, button)
     print('mouse button %d pressed at %d, %d', button, x, y)
     if button == "l" then
         printf('checking %d buttons', #buttons)
         for k, v in pairs(buttons) do
             local ins = insideBox( x, y, v.x - (v.w/2), v.y - (v.h/2), v.w, v.h)
             printf('%d, %d is%sinside button %s (%d, %d, %d, %d)',
                 ins and ' ' or ' not ', k, x, y, v.x, v.y, v.w, v.h)
             if ins then
                 print('executing action', v.action)
                 if v.action == "play" then
                     loadState("game")
                 elseif v.action == "quit" then
                     love.event.quit()
                 end
             end
         end
     end
 end
```

You should also used meaningful variables names. `v` can be `button`. What is `k`? An index? Then perhaps `i` or `index`. Is it a name? Then `name`. So on and so forth. `k` tells us nothing.